# Getting "<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>" file not found in freahIM Application

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Am working in chat application, In this application i need to integrate what'sapp clone application into my app, So i have download the freshIM app from the google, But lot of files are missed in that application, i have found the missing files from google and i had implement ed in my freshIm app, But finally i got

```
                   **"<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>" file not found in "AsyncImage" class**.
```

So please any one help to solve this issue, Am facing this issue last 2 days.Can any one tell me why this issue occurring.

Please let me know any other available source for what's app clone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` is for Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch (i.e. OSX not iOS) and simply does not exist in the iOS SDK (which is the reason for the error).

You want:

`<UIKit/UIKit.h>`

Comment: hi sir, thanks for your reply, i got this error in AsyncImage.h file sir, so u said that file for cocoa right? i get that lib file from google, so i need to get that file for cocoa touch right??

Comment: @user1547937 Yes; looks like that library is intended to be used in OSX.

Comment: sorry for asking, can u have any link for cocoa touch AsyncImage.h file, am facing this issue last 2 days sir.

Comment: @user1547937 Sorry, no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Subclasses of NSObject (at least on the iPhone) do not import the Cocoa.h header. Instead, they import Foundation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```